# Create an if else statement in c++

Tags: c++

i am a complete newbie to C programming language. i am trying to create an if statement with the following code but im not sure how to go about it. I need "producerHelper.SetPrefix("/myprefix1")" to do another command.  Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

```
bool (producerHelper.SetPrefix("/myprefix")) = True;  
if ( True )
{
 producerHelper.SetAttribute("ContentDirectory", StringValue("/home/multimedia_testing/svc720"));
}
else
{
producerHelper.SetAttribute("ContentDirectory", StringValue("/home/multimedia_testing/svc360"));
}
```

Comment: Get yourself a book.

Comment: You might want to buy a book and work methodically through that. Asking people on the internet is not such a great way to learn a language like `C++`. **Books:** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list

Comment: To be honest im not trying to learn the language, i am from a python background but currently doing a project creating scenarios in ndnSIM, a network simulator,which is c++ based, i am only trying to alter certain aspects of pre written code to suit my scenarios. I have no time to learn another language for the little bit of it i need.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose what you want is this:

```
bool res = producerHelper.SetPrefix("/myprefix");  
if ( res )
{
 producerHelper.SetAttribute("ContentDirectory", StringValue("/home/multimedia_testing/svc720"));
}
else
{
producerHelper.SetAttribute("ContentDirectory", StringValue("/home/multimedia_testing/svc360"));
}
```

Comment: thank you for the help, i appreciate it.